# Calling batch commands from python

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, batch-file, cmd

I am using python with some external program API in order to automate some stuff.
Have in mind that these "extpro" and "--file" and "--dont-breakaway-from-job" are built in commands that I have to use, my code looks like this:

```
send = os.system('extpro --file '(os.path.join(base_dir, extpr_path))' --dont-breakaway-from-job')
```

Error that I am getting is on the --dont-breakaway-from-job, saying Expected ")" pylance.

But when I try this there is no error:

```
send = os.system('extpro --file "C:/user/program/run.exe" --dont-breakaway-from-job')
```

Anyone have idea what might be behind this behavior?
Is there a way maybe to split whole command into two or three?

Any advice is welcome, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.path.join` returns `str` object, thus your

```py
'extpro --file '(os.path.join(base_dir, extpr_path))' --dont-breakaway-from-job'
```

expands into:

```py
'extpro --file '"<whatever that path is>"' --dont-breakaway-from-job'
               ^
```

In the position marked with `^` the string ends. And, since `os.system` expects only one single parameter, pylance (and interpreter too) supposes, that this parameter is already passed and throws an error, that closing bracket is expected.

Interpreter doesn't concatenate `os.path.join` result with string before it, because it doesn't know, that `os.path.join` is a string. Function call will become string only in runtime.

However, your second variant contains `'some str "inner str" some more'`. Python interpreter sees string, starting with `'` (single qotation mark) and looks for a matching pair, that will mean end of the string. All `"` (double quotation marks) between single ones are considered part of the string.

Solution is simple. You can do any of:

```py
# Concatenating strings with +
send = os.system('extpro --file "'+ os.path.join(base_dir, extpr_path) + '" --dont-breakaway-from-job')
# Using format (or f-strings, ifyou're using python 3.6+)
send = os.system('extpro --file "{}" --dont-breakaway-from-job'.format(os.path.join(base_dir, extpr_path)))
# or
send = os.system(f'extpro --file "{os.path.join(base_dir, extpr_path)}" --dont-breakaway-from-job')
```

In any of 3 variations it's worth wrapping `os.path.join` results with `"` (double quotation mark) in case it contains spaces or other undesired symbols, that may e parsed incorrectly

Answer (score 1):

If i understood it right, the issue is that you need to concatenate the string with quotation marks? If that is the case, you can use the following

```
send = os.system("extpro --file \""+os.path.join(base_dir, extpr_path)+"\" --dont-breakaway-from-job")
```

The os.path.join returns a string which needs to be concatenated using +. Furthermore, you need to include quotation marks around `os.path.join`. This can be achieved in many ways, but the one i used in this answer is `\"`.

Answer (score 1):

Your line `send = os.system('extpro --file '(os.path.join(base_dir, extpr_path))' --dont-breakaway-from-job')` doesn't create the string that you expect/need and doesn't concatenate `'extpro --file '` with the filepath (within `"`!) and the `' --dont-breakaway-from-job'`).

The easiest solution might be to use a F-string:

```
send = os.system(f'extpro --file "{os.path.join(base_dir, extpr_path)}" --dont-breakaway-from-job')
```

Important here is also to add `"` to the string, since `os.path.join(...)` doesn't create a string with the `"`.